# Setup Cherrypy with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cgi, wsgi, cherrypy

Can someone please show me how to get cherrypy to work with Google App Engine, I have made applications with cherrypys built in server, but I have no idea how to make an app that works with WSGI and GAE.

I have read the documentation for cherrypy and GAE but can't find anything. And I would prefer cherrypy to the webapp2 which is in the GAE example.

Comment: What have you researched thus far? For example, a quick Google search led me to [this](http://boodebr.org/main/python/cherrypy-under-google-appserver) article and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/379352/1101070) similar SO question. Did you come across these two resources and were they any help?

Comment: I did, but I didnt use the boodebr one, I keep getting told that it cant find cherrypy but this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379352/how-to-run-the-cherrypy-web-server-in-the-google-app-engine, Ill try it now, thanks

Comment: Its working, thank you, I didnt think to put cherrypy in the root folder

Comment: Hmm - annoyingly this answer is the top google hit for the question - and Marvin's link was broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that cherrypy was not in the root of the working directory, all of which I uploaded with the app engine tool. Not 100% sure if its the correct way to use GAE but it works.