# First steps for "Hello World" with CherryPy and Google App Engine: any updated guides?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cherrypy

First, let me just say that I have searched for information on this topic; there are a number of stackoverflow posts that all reference the same blog post from 2008:

http://boodebr.org/main/python/cherrypy-under-google-appserver#comment-51142

I understand that the new CherryPy version no longer requires the patch this blog post mentions. I have the cherrypy folder in the root of my GAE app - and I don't get an error when I import it in my program - but beyond the "import cherrypy" line, I can't get it to work.  I'm not sure how to change the app.yaml file to properly reflect that I am using cherrypy, and not webbapp2 (or if that is important).

Is someone aware of an updated tutorial that could walk me through CherryPy/GAE? Or, could someone be so kind as to post the simple hello world program that will work using cherrypy in GAE?

Edit: If it helps, here's the code I have in main.py right now - it returns two 404 errors from cherrypy.

```
import cherrypy
import wsgiref.handlers 

class Root:
def index(self):
    return "Hello, CherryPy!"


app = cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), "/")
wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(app)
```

Comment: Have you searched "CherryPy App Engine" in either the web or StackOverflow? I think CherryPy has an WSGI interface, so it's very easy to run it especially with Python2.7 runtime.

Comment: Takashi, I have searched both the web and StackOverflow for information. Unfortunately, there is no exact example available of the hello world program for CherryPy in GAE. EG: a slight mod of first response to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379352/how-to-run-the-cherrypy-web-server-in-the-google-app-engine?rq=1
gets me the specified text, but it is repeated twice and it sandwiches  some random page/html information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've a website running in GAE with cherrypy, it is very straight forward, you code is correct but you are not exposing the `index` method that explain the `404`.

Anyway you should use the [run_wsgi_app](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/utilmodule) that GAE provides, so your code will look like this:

```
import cherrypy
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class Root(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return 'Hello CherryPy!'

app = cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), '/')
run_wsgi_app(app)
```